# Lebsegue measure of $\{ 0<x \leq 1: x \sin \left(\frac{\pi}{2x}\right) \geq 0 \}$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

> Find the Lebsegue measure of the set $A= \left\{ 0<x \leq 1: x \sin \left(\frac{\pi}{2x}\right) \geq 0 \right\}$.

The answer given is $1 - \ln \sqrt{2}$.

**My thought:** I only know that Lebsegue measure of countable set is zero (The Lebesgue measure of an uncountable set is not necessarily positive).

Kindly help me.

Comment: Sorry, could you rewrite the "1-In$\sqrt{2}$ part to make it more clear what that is supposed to say? Is it $1-\ln\sqrt{2}$?

Comment: Although this doesn't help you right now, not every uncountable set has positive measure.

Comment: Yes..   Ben S....I have edited it.

Comment: If $x>0$ then $x\sin\dots\geq0\iff\sin\dots\geq0$

Comment: Isn't $x\sin(\pi x/2) \geq 0$ for all $x\in [0,1]$?

Comment: I think $\frac{\pi}{2x}$, rather than $\frac{\pi x}{2}$, is meant.

Comment: You are dealing with a countable union of disjoint intervals. Summing up their lengths gives you the answer to the question.

Comment: drhab...then (π/2x)≦π→ x≧1/2 .

Comment: @mathlover That works for $\frac{\pi}{2 x} \in [0,\pi]$. But it would also work for $\frac{\pi}{2x} \in [2\pi,3\pi]$, and so forth.

Comment: but I couldn't reach the answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\sin(x)$ is nonnegative for $x \in [2n\pi,(2n+1)\pi]$ for each integer $n$. So you should solve $\frac{\pi}{2x} \in [2n\pi,(2n+1)\pi]$ for each integer $n$. You get $x \in \left [ \frac{1}{4n+2},\frac{1}{4n} \right ]$ for $n \neq 0$ and $x \in [1/2,\infty)$ for $n=0$. (Check this yourself.) So your answer is the sum of the lengths of all these intervals when they are intersected with $[0,1]$. Only the zeroth one, which is $[1/2,\infty)$ has any piece not in $[0,1]$, so that contributes $1/2$. The rest contribute

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{4n} - \frac{1}{4n+2}.$$

Deriving the value of this sum from first principles is not a trivial matter. But since you are given the final answer, you can check it by using the Maclaurin series of $f(x)=\ln(1+x)$. Note that $\ln(\sqrt{2})=\frac{1}{2} \ln(2)$; so it is enough to show that the sum above is $\frac{1-\ln(2)}{2}$.

Comment: Thanks Ian..really great explanation!!!

Comment: awesome explanation..

Comment: I still do not know how to find the sum?

Comment: @MANI If you're working from scratch then you are in trouble, but the idea is to do some algebraic manipulation on $\ln(2)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}/n$ instead of working from scratch. You want to include the multiples of 4 with a plus sign and the even numbers besides 2 that are not multiples of 4 with a minus sign. You can get rid of the odd numbers by dividing by 2. This leaves the denominator of 2 behind, so you have to subtract 1/2 to get rid of that. Now the signs are all backwards, so you multiply by $-1$ and now you're good.